# Admin Page Showing Blank

Tags: php, database

Created a PHP Website, Example.com and Login Page is example.com/admin

When I am filling the username and password details at example.com/admin.

Page Successfully loaded and showing successful redirecting to you but dashboard or admin panel showing blank screen.

check below error log

```
2019/05/04 02:21:52 [emerg] 16768#16768: unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:92
2019/05/04 02:23:21 [notice] 16780#16780: signal process started

  thrown in /var/www/html/core/library/geoip.inc on line 572" while reading response header from upstream, client: 171.79.224.202, server: 157.230.229.11, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "157.230.229.11"
2019/05/04 03:23:16 [error] 30120#30120: *187 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in /var/www/html/core/library/geoip.inc:572
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/core/library/geoip.inc(464): _geoip_seek_country(Object(GeoIP), 2874138826)
#1 /var/www/html/core/library/geoip.inc(503): geoip_country_id_by_addr(Object(GeoIP), '171.79.224.202')
#2 /var/www/html/admin/controllers/dashboard.php(106): geoip_country_name_by_addr(Object(GeoIP), '171.79.224.202')
#3 /var/www/html/admin/app.php(129): require('/var/www/html/a...')
#4 /var/www/html/admin/index.php(41): require('/var/www/html/a...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/core/library/geoip.inc on line 572" while reading response header from upstream, client: 171.79.224.202, server: 157.230.229.11, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "157.230.229.11"
```

nginx/sites-available/default file is

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 157.230.229.11;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

also when I'm clicking any of page / sub-page showing homepage or if changed to it then is showing 404 not found nginx error but homepage works file.

Please Help me any one with this

Comment: Please Check you .htaccess file.

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinksOptions -IndexesRewriteEngine onRewriteBase/<FilesMatch "\.(inc|sql|bak|ini|tdata|sdata|addonpk)$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch><IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
</IfModule><IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?route=$1/$2 [L] 
</IfModule><IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?route=$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

Comment: this is .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Comment: @Vijay Singh : Normal try this.

Comment: Please tell me the solution - 2019/05/04 02:21:52 [emerg] 16768#16768: unexpected end of file, expecting "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:92 check above default file